# Faceted Search Block displays values from other facet blocks

Tags: 7, entities, blocks, search

I'm using the Faceted Search API (drupal 7) and followed this Tutorial: [Part 1](http://webwash.net/tutorials/intro-search-api-part-1-how-create-search-pages) and [Part 2](http://webwash.net/tutorials/intro-search-api-part-2-faceted-search)

All worked fine but there's a little Problem with the Values each Block displays [image]

"Kategorie" and "Serie" are both showing all selected Fields instead just the related. But if i check one Value, which is not related to the "Kategorie" Field, I don't get any results so the search works fine but displaying the values doesn't.

I deleted all and made the search page from scratch like the tutorial described but i've got the same issue all over again. Also i checked the CSS settings for my facet blocks. Indexing all again didn't help, neither does running Cron again.

Does someone have any clues?

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the answer by myself. Never thought it would be such a little setting:

If you're going to index a "text field" (and maybe going to enable the related facet block), make sure the text field is declared as **string** instead of **fulltext**.

Just go to -> **Search API** >> edit the correlating index >> **Fields**

and check the textfields. Following this you just have to re-index the items.